# Eclipse Java version not fully updating

Tags: java, eclipse

I dwonloaded JDK8 and in Eclipse Preferences->Java->Complier,
I left it at 1.7, but in Configure, I selected the jdk1.8 path and unckecked the jre7.

---

However, when my Project builds, it is still looking trying to look for tools.jar under the old jre7 path. Why isnt it picking up the jdk1.8 path?
When I click on the Project and righlt-click Properties, its "Java Build Path" is showing all the old jre7 lib paths.

---

Why didnt they all get updated to use the new path I added in the Preferences?
Im a little confused as to the mechanism here. What needs to be done to update the paths inside the project? I obviously dont want to do it manually one project at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update the installed JREs?

There are also project specific library settings that will need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you have four important settings:

1.) `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs` will display all Eclipse-Known JREs/ JDKs and allow you to add your own ones. Within this view you select your default JDK if nothing else has been specified by the project this JDK will be used to compile/ run projects

2.) `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler` allows to define Compiler-settings regardless of the installed JREs. Note: If you for example select a compiler compliance level of 1.6 while a 1.8 JDK was selected as default you will see a corresponding warning in this screen.

3.) `Right click project -> Properties -> Java Compiler` allows to override the default settings as defined in the two points described above on a project level. The above two default settings will act as default for any project unless `Enable project specific settings` in this view has been activated.

4.) `Right click project -> Properties -> Java Build Path` in the tab `Libraries` you should see a entry `JRE System Library [Version]` - if you select it and press `Edit...` you will be able to select between `Execution environment` (i expect this is where your 1.7 is configured - i have no clue where they come from but there is a entry for nearly every java version), `Alternate JRE:` (youre able to select the ones you have installed) and `workspace default JRE` (the one selected of the installed JREs).

So to come back to your question i assume after you have your JDK installed in the first option (of the 3 above ones) you will have to adjust your project settings - in case of enabled project specific settings you will have to enable, in case of the last point select your workspace default JDK for any project.

Comment: My Compiler is 1.7 and my Installed JREs is 1.8 path, so in my Project, why are all the libraries looking at the jre7 paths? I dont want to go to each project and update the path to 1.8 - that defeats the whole point of using Preferences.

Comment: Did you check that your projects dont have "Enable project specific settings" enabled so they take the configurations from the Installed Jre/ Compiler settings?

Comment: Oh, i found one more setting - updating the answer

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project properties -> Project facets -> Java -> change the version

Note: Remove other installed JREs and keep only required one.